How to publish an Open Telemetry custom metric from Airflow?
I'm trying to publish a custom metric using Open Telemetry.
I'm running Airflow 2.9.2, an OTel collector, Prometheus and Grafana in Docker containers on my laptop. The "out of the box" Airflow metrics are working fine, meaning I can see them in the collector and Grafana, so I know my setup is working.
I have the following DAG.
When I run it as a unit test on my laptop, it works - meaning it publishes the metric to the collector and is visible in Grafana. However, when I run the DAG in Airflow, the metric does not get published. Further, the DAG succeeds and no errors are thrown.
Somewhere along my research, I found reader.force_flush() and provider.force_flush() but neither of those worked.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os
from random import randint

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.metric_exporter import OTLPMetricExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 7, 1),
    'email': [],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': 30,
}

otel_host = os.getenv('AIRFLOW__METRICS__OTEL_HOST', 'localhost')
otel_port = os.getenv('AIRFLOW__METRICS__OTEL_PORT', '24317')
endpoint = f'http://{otel_host}:{otel_port}'

# Set up the Metric Exporter
exporter = OTLPMetricExporter(endpoint=endpoint, insecure=True)

# Set up the Metric Reader
reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(exporter)

# Set up the Meter Provider
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[reader])
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)

# Create a Meter
meter = metrics.get_meter(__name__)

# Create a custom metric
gauge = meter.create_gauge(
    name='hanks_gauge_from_airflow',
    description=f'hanks custom gauge from airflow',
    unit='int',
)


def publish_custom_metric(**context):
    i = randint(1, 100)
    ts = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    attributes = {'ts': ts}

    # Record a value to the gauge
    gauge.set(i, attributes)

    logging.info(i)
    logging.info(ts)
    logging.info(endpoint)

    return


with DAG(
    dag_id='hanks_otel_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule='* * * * *',
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    # giving the task a very short name because OTel is cluttering the log with the following WARNING:
    # "...exceeds OpenTelemetry's name length limit of 63 characters and will be truncated to..."
    ht1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='ht1',
        python_callable=publish_custom_metric,
    )

UPDATE / MORE INFO:
I realized one of the import statements was wrong. I was using the grpc exporter, but Airflow is configured to use the http port.
So you have to do either this (http):
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.http.metric_exporter import OTLPMetricExporter
exporter = OTLPMetricExporter(endpoint=f'http://{otel_host}:{http_port}/v1/metrics')

or this (grpc):
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.metric_exporter import OTLPMetricExporter
exporter = OTLPMetricExporter(endpoint=f'http://{otel_host}:{grpc_port}')

I also confirmed I have connectivity to the endpoint by adding this task in the DAG:
test_endpoint = BashOperator(
    task_id='test_endpoint',
    bash_command=f"curl -v -d {{}} -H 'Content-Type: application/json' {endpoint}"
)

